Проблема с передачей указателя на строку ostringstream
По совету ChatGPT писал код для работы с cURL, в котором был фрагмент
    std::ostringstream postFields;
    // Долгая запись в postFields...
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postFields.str().c_str());

Все это не работало - тело запроса никак не передавалось. Как будто его нет. Путем проб и ошибок нашел, что проблема во второй строке.
Стоило сделать так:
    std::string g = postFields.str();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, g.c_str());

или даже
    const std::string& g = postFields.str();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, g.c_str());

как все отлично работало.
У меня подозрения, что это связано с какими-то тонкостями передачи - получить строку, а потом из нее указатель, и что-то по дороге портится, вроде как с возвратом локальной переменной из функции.
Поэтому вопрос - я прав ли нет? Если нет, то в чем тогда дело - почему начальный код не работает, если прав - то расскажите подробнее. И как вообще находить такие странны места в языке.

Время жизни заканчивается после вызова функции, после этого временный объект умирает. Курл, мог не сохранить данные до вызова perform

Это можно выяснить при работе с отладчиком. Остановиться переключиться в режим представления Ассемблера и посмотреть. Конечно, без знания элементарных навыков - это сложно. Тогда можно предположить. В первом случае переменная отправляется в Стек (проталкивается в регистр), во втором случае, здесь может быть два варианта. В первом, компилятор выделяет участок в памяти для переменной. Второй вариант - создается жесткая ссылка в сегменте программы как глобальная переменная.

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка

Начинаем с очевидных вещей:
std::ostringstream::str() возвращает строку по значению, эта строка умирает в конце текущего выражения (грубо говоря, на ближайшем ;, т.е. в конце текущей строки кода).
Это было бы нормально, если бы curl_easy_setopt делал себе копию строки, но судя по всему, он ее не делает, и расчитывает на то, что строка продолжит существовать.
И действительно, если открыть мануал:

Strings passed to libcurl as char * arguments, are copied by the library; the string storage associated to the pointer argument may be discarded or reused after curl_easy_setopt returns. The only exception to this rule is really CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but the alternative that copies the string CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS has some usage characteristics you need to read up on.

Т.е. если не хочется хранить строку самому, то нужно использовать CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.

Ну и мелочь: Такой вызов .str() создает лишнюю копию строки. Правильнее так: std::move(postFields).str().
